# Is it possible to extract slides from powerpoint and save them as images using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerpoint, sails.js

We are curently developing an app, which runs on sailsjs (node + mongo) as a backend.

Our clinet wishes to have a specific funcionality, which is uploading a *.ppt files and possibly extract all slides and save them as images (at least, much better would be to extract all texts and images separately - but let's not make it more difficult for now ;))

So my question is, can it be achieved somehow with nodejs and/or maybe some other tools which would cooperate with our app?

Scenario is simple:
 - user uploads a *.ppt
 - application returns a set of images which represents all slides

Thanks for any tips/links/solutions.

Comment: Did my answer helped eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this useful:

www.aspose.com -

> Aspose.Slides for Cloud is a REST based API which allows you to read, edit and convert PowerPoint documents in the cloud. You can convert PowerPoint documents into various other formats like TIFF, PDF, PPTX, XPS and PPT etc. You can extract the contents like text and images from the PowerPoint documents.

In the following link you can find how to save a slide to image using their api, they also have a nodejs example. [aspose.com - slide to image](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidescloud/Save+a+PowerPoint+Slide+as+Image+with+Default+Size)

Good luck,

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer. It seems like aspose is currently the only working solution. Licence is already bought so gonna make some PoC soon ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have created Node.js package to convert files.
The package does following things

- Convert PDF to PNG
- Convert PPT to PDF
- Convert PPT to PNG

Here is the link of the project [GITHUB](https://github.com/vivekb084/FileFormatConverter)

OR

Download Node package by

```
npm i file-format-converter
```

Comment: Installation not working

Error that I am getting: 

npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No versions available for file-format-converter

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: <file_location>